# Re-entering a Schengen country

Tags: visas, schengen, germany

I traveled from Israel to Germany on September 5th and left on September 15th to go back to Israel, where I am now. I want to enter Germany again on December 7th.

I know the Schengen visa rule says you can stay up to 90 days, every 6 months from the date of entry but I left after 10 days and want to enter again after more than 3 months from the date of entry (but less than 6 months).

Can I do it?

Comment: Yes, you can (assuming you're an Israeli citizen and therefore don't need a visa, otherwise your visa would specify a period of validity, maximum stay *and number of entries*, which could make a difference). See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule for all the details.

Comment: So, does it mean I can leave and re-enter Germany as much as I want during the 6 months period, as long as my numeours visits all together did not last for more than 90 days?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how this rules works.

Comment: @Relaxed It might be worth mentioning the rolling nature of the 180-day period as you outlined here: http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/21461/19400.  As I understand it, under the old rules, it would have been possible to stay for 179 consecutive days by visiting for a day, waiting 90 days, and then entering; this is no longer possible.

Comment: @phoog Yes, exactly, good point!